# Is there a shorter way to achieve this filter of data types?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, switch-statement

I have to come up with a function that pushes data into its own category. This is what I made & it passes the tests required. My question is if there is a much shorter way in ES6 to write this, don´t really like using switches.

```
function filterTypes(values) {
  const result = {
    number: [],
    string: [],
    object: [],
    others: [],
  };

  for (const value of values) {
    switch (typeof value) {
      case "number":
        result.number.push(value);
        break;
      case "string":
        result.string.push(value);
        break;
      case "object":
        // null is a falsy object so if null --> push to others
        value === null ? result.others.push(value) : result.object.push(value);
        break;
      default:
        // undefined, bigint, symbol, boolean, function
        result.others.push(value);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: You could replace the `for` loop with `reduce()` or `forEach()`, but I don't think there's a way to simplify the `switch`.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the first place? Maybe you should redesign whatever is creating the array with mixed data types, and have it return things in different arrays.

Comment: It`s a technical challenge for an interview, that´s how they gave it to me, can´t redesign it I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the keys of your object match the string value you get when you use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), you can use the result of calling `typeof` on each `value` to determine the key you want to push to. You can add some expectations such as if the value is `null` to use `"other"` as the key instead of "object". If the `typeof` the value isn't in your `result` object you're building, you can also choose `"other"` (below I've used [`Object.hasOwn()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn) to check if the type is in the object which is part of *ECMAScript 2022*, you can use [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) or the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) for older browser support).

See the example below (see browser console to view big int):

```js
function filterTypes(values) {
  const result = {number: [], string: [], object: [], others: []};
  for(const value of values) {
    const type = typeof value;
    const key = value === null || !Object.hasOwn(result, type) ? "others" : type;
    result[key].push(value);
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(filterTypes([0, "a", {x: 1}, 1n, null, true]));
```

A similar result can be achieved if you use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), but a regular `for...of` loop is easier to read in my opinion. In the below example I'm building up an accumulated object with the [spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) which is returned from the reduce callback, that also has an updated `key` value to hold a new array with the current value:

```js
const filterTypes = values => values.reduce((acc, value) => {
  const type = typeof value;
  const key = value === null || !Object.hasOwn(acc, type) ? "others" : type;
  return {...acc, [key]: [...acc[key], value]};
}, {number: [], string: [], object: [], others: []});

console.log(filterTypes([0, "a", {x: 1}, 1n, null, true]));
```

Comment: So, bigint always returns null?

Comment: @Mary1993 no, that's just the code snippet console output doing that. See your actual browser console to see the correct output